# How to insert IEnumerable<XElement> object into SQL Server table?

Tags: c#, xelement

I have created below code to get Users from XML:

```
        string userName = "user";
        string password = "password";
        string uri = @"uri";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);  
        Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(uri);
        XElement output = XElement.Load(stream);
        IEnumerable<XElement> users = from el in output.Elements() select el;

        foreach (XElement str in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
```

Result:

```
        <User>
          <ObjectId>3cbde</ObjectId> 
          <Alias>alias</Alias> 
          <DisplayName>Display Name</DisplayName> 
          <TimeZone>0</TimeZone> 
          <Language>0</Language> 
          <ListInDirectory>false</ListInDirectory> 
          <IsVmEnrolled>true</IsVmEnrolled> 
        </User>
```

Now I would like to insert the data into database, but I would like to put each field as separate column - table in database has columns: **ObjectId**, **DisplayName**, **TimeZone** and etc.
Could you please give me some advices how it can be easily done? Do I need to convert it into DataTable or else?

Comment: There is never any reason to write `from x in y select x`

Comment: @SLaks I am new in Linq:) Could you please direct me into right page?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx - Here what I found and used it.

Comment: The point of LINQ queries is if you need to add things like `where` clauses.  If you don't, they're useless.

Comment: Do you use any ORM such as Entity Framework to do your database transactions or just straight SqlClient/SqlCommand ?

Comment: @Francis I just want to straight insert values into database.

Comment: @SLaks So how can I do it without Linq? Because as You said it is pointless.

Comment: Is the content in the "Result" block a sample of the input XML you wish to use ?

Comment: `output.Elements()` is already an `IEnumerable<XElement>`

Comment: @Francis Result blocs is result of the execution of c# code. I just wanted to show what is my result.

Comment: I would indeed use a DataTable. If there is nothing preventing you from naming the table fields the same as the XML node names, that could simplify it. If you need an example, I can post something to give you an idea.

Comment: @Francis I was thinking about DataTable. Could you please share some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, I'm taking the XML stream locally, for testing purpose. Just change it to your method of getting the stream (WebClient). Also used `SqlBulkCopy`, I don't see any downsides of doing so plus, if you end up having a lot of rows to insert, that'll be faster. There are probably better ways to refactor this, but roughly:

```
        SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy("ConnectionString...");
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "PhysicalTableName";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("PhysicalTableName");


        dt.Columns.Add("ObjectId");
        dt.Columns.Add("Alias");
        dt.Columns.Add("DisplayName");
        dt.Columns.Add("TimeZone");
        dt.Columns.Add("Language");
        dt.Columns.Add("ListInDirectory");
        dt.Columns.Add("IsVmEnrolled");


        XElement output = XElement.Load("c:\\temp\\input.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> users = output.Elements();

        foreach (XElement str in users)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (XElement node in str.Elements())
            {
                dr[node.Name.LocalName] = node.Value;
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
```

I did not have any information on the schema of your tables so by default in this example, all the columns are of type `String`.

Do not forget about exception handling as well.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I think that faster will be using build in MSSQL stored procedure sp_xml_preparedocument and then use Select * from OpenXML.