# What is the best way to insert Bulk Xml (XElement) data to Sql server Table using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a XElement Object, I need to insert this into Sql Server Table using C#. (the XML file contains more than 2 lakhs records)

Can you help me in this? OR else any alternate?

Comment: you should use XmlWriter if the data is huge in an xml file rather than loading it in memory at once.

Comment: you can see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474672/put-xelement-into-database), may be helful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XElement output = XElement.Load("c:\\temp\\input.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> users = output.Elements(); 

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("CLIENT_INPUT_MHS_ID", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("CLIENT_INPUT_MHS_GUID",typeof(Guid));
                dt.Columns.Add("ITEM", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("ITEM_ID", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("ITEM_NUMBER", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("CATEGORY", typeof(string));        

        foreach (XElement str in users)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (XElement node in str.Elements())
            {
                dr[node.Name.LocalName] = node.Value;
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy("ConnectionString...");
 using (bulkCopy )
                {
                    bulkCopy .BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                    bulkCopy .ColumnMappings.Add(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName, "CLIENT_INPUT_MHS_ID");
                    bulkCopy .ColumnMappings.Add(dt.Columns[1].ColumnName, "CLIENT_INPUT_MHS_GUID");
                    bulkCopy .ColumnMappings.Add(dt.Columns[2].ColumnName, "ITEM");
                    bulkCopy .ColumnMappings.Add(dt.Columns[3].ColumnName, "ITEM_ID");
                    bulkCopy .ColumnMappings.Add(dt.Columns[4].ColumnName, "ITEM_NUMBER");
                    bulkCopy .ColumnMappings.Add(dt.Columns[5].ColumnName, "CATEGORY");
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "DestinationTableName";                   
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt); }



Its working fine with my scenario.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, first load data from XML, then DataSet and then go for SQL Bulk Copy. Things would be easy then onward.

Loading XML data to DataSet can be done as below:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("xml file path");
```